# Loading tokens into map container in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I would need help with loading each substring/token in a container. In my code, I separate each indiviual line from a file and put it in this format.

> Element1 Key1 Key2 Key3 (and so on)

After that I separate each individual sub-string.
The problem is, that I don't acutally know how to put it in  map < string, set < string > > subjects; container. Below is the code I have right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 
bool transform  ( const char * inFile,
              const char * outFile )
{
  map<string, set<string> > subjects;
  ifstream inf(inFile);
  ofstream outf(outFile);
  string line;
  while(getline(inf, line))
   {
      if(line[0]=='#') continue; // skipping of the commented lines
      int len;
      len=line.length();
      for(int i=0; i<(len-1);i++) // putting space on the place of ':' and ','
       {
           if(line[i]==':' || line[i]==',') {line[i]=' ';}
       }
      for(int i=0; i<(len-1);i++) //merging of the duplicated white spaces
       {
           if(line[i]==' ' && line[i+1]==' ') {line[i]=0;}
       }
      string s;
      istringstream f(line);
      while (std::getline(f, s, ' ')) //tokenization
       {
           //here i need to load each sub-string in the container, the first is element and after that comes the keys.
       }

   }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm quite new to C++, so I am even not sure how to work with the container exactly. I got line where on the first place is the element and after that the keys to which the element is connected. In the end I need to print on each line one Key and all the elements connected with this Key. I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Your "merging of duplicated white space" won't work - you'd need to use `erase`, but there's no point as once you have the `istringstream` `f` (with however much whitespace between tokens), you can just do `if (f >> element) while (f >> key) subjects[element].insert(key);` (assuming you create `string`s `element` and `key`).

Comment: But I need somehow to tell the function that on the first place on line, that is element and after that are keys.

Comment: Ad actually when do `line[i]=0;` it works (according to testing output), but when I tried using `line.erase(i,1)` it let some white spaces still there.

Comment: `if (f >> element) while (f >> key)` takes care of reading the element then however-many keys, and using `>>` instead of `getline` also handles multiple whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the code to pump a map < string, set < string > >  looks like this...

This code assumes that all the weird tokenizing and such is encapsulated in a FileReader class which is not defined here.

```
std::map <string, std::set<string> > FileToStringMap (std::string filename)
{
  FileReader my_reader (filename);

  std::map <string, std::set<string> > my_map;

  std::string curr_key;
  while (my_reader.getKey(curr_key))
  {
    std::set<string> value_set;

    std::string curr_value_elem;
    while (my_reader.getValue(curr_value_elem))
    {
      value_set.insert(curr_value_elem);
    }

    my_map.insert (std::make_pair(curr_key, value_set));
  }

  return my_map;
}
```

**A note about notation:** In general, the first element type of a map is referred to as the **key** and other data is referred to as the **value**.  I use this practice in my code, even though in your question the term **key** is used differently.

Answer (score 0):

You Don't have replace the delimiters `; , <space>`, just use them.
This is sample code which returns a vector of strings(in your case)

```
std::vector keys;
std::string element1;
size_t last_cur_pos = 0;
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    if( line[i]==':' || line[i]==',' || line[i] == ' ' || i == (line.length()-1))
    {
        std::string temp = line.substr(last_cur_pos, (i-last_cur_pos));
        if(last_cur_pos == 0)
           element1 = temp;
        else
           keys.push_back(temp);
        last_cur_pos = i + 1;
    }
}
// Considering your map is subjects<string, vector<string>> then;
subjects[element1] = keys;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the main problem here is the `map<string, set<string> > subjects` . I don't know, how to load it inside this structure.